# Must verb always be before 下去?

Tags: sentence-structure

I want to say:

```
我吃下去 = I continue eating.
```

Must verb always be before 下去?

or is `我下去吃` also correct?

The same for other verbs like `等`.

```
我等下去 = I continue wating.
```

or is `我下去等` also correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers stated, 下去 can function as a directional/result word particle for 'down'  e.g. 吞下去; It can also function as a verb for 'go down' e.g. 我要下去

But when 下去 is functioning as an **adverb** for "**continue**". It must be placed after a verb. e.g. 等下去

> *I want to say:*

> *我吃下去 = I continue eating.*

To avoid confusion, you can write "我(繼續)吃下去" or simply "我繼續吃".

Another way to make "我吃下去 (I continue eating) not ambiguous is to add more context. For example, 我再吃下去也不會喜歡上這東西

Comment: 'go down' in English can have different meanings depending on the context. How about `我要下去`? Does it always mean `I want to go downstairs` in any context or it can also have different meanings in different contexts?

Comment: @ O Connor  我要下去 (I want to go down) mean someone wants to descend/ get down from a high place, for example, a building, a hill, or even from a stage

Comment: @OConnor In some cases where the situation/idea expressed involves moving in a downwards direction but there are no stairs involved, it would be inappropriate to translate using the word "downstairs". // In https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_down there are 9 meanings/usages given for "go down" as a verb. So this usage of 下去 matches item #2 ("To descend; to move from a higher place to a lower one.") on wikipedia. It doesn't fit with the other items (1; 3-9).

Answer (score 1):

我吃下去 means you swallow/take something. e.g. 我吃下去那醫師開的感冒藥後，有點昏昏欲睡。

我下去吃 means you go downstairs to somewhere to eat something. e.g. 我要下去吃早餐了.

我等下去 means I will go somewhere after a while. e.g. Q: 你甚麼時候過來一起打球？ A:我等下去！

我下去等 means you go downstairs and wait someone in front of door(or somewhere). e.g. Q: Uber外送快送到了！ A: 我下去等。

Comment: 我觉得题主说的“等下去”是“一直等下去”的“等下去”，不是“等一下去”的“等下去”

Comment: `我等下去 means I will go somewhere after a while`? Does `我等下去` not just simply mean `I keep/continue wating`?

Comment: Maybe someone would say 我等下去 instead of 我等(一)下(就)去. But people don't usually reduce 等一下 to 等下

Answer (score 1):

These are 3 different situation

1， In 吃下，咽下，吞下，喝下,  下 means "down into the stomach".

2， In 等下去，看下去，持续下去，这样下去，继续下去，下去 means continue. You can think of a process as a flow and 下去 is continuing the process.

3， 下去 Itself means go down stairs. So when you say 我下去吃，我下去等, that means you are going to eat/wait downstairs.

我吃下去 Is more likelihood to be understood as the first situation. If you want to say "I continue eating" It can be 我继续吃，我接着吃.